# Bootstrap booking grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on a booking grid **with bootstrap** trying to make responsive a previous design.

Here is the current design on the left vs mockup on the right,

[link to image](http://s9.postimg.org/r4ln7q0pr/gridbootstrap.png)

As you can see, in the top is the current week (in red) with the arrows in the sides.
Then, the current dates (in white).

I'm want to use only 8 columns

This is what i got so far... thanks for the help in advance.

```
<div class="grid-calendar">
    <div class="row calendar-week-header">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>s</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>M</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>T</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>W</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>T</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>F</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>S</span></div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row calendar-week">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>31</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>1</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>2</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>3</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>4</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>5</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>6</span></div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row calendar-week">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>7</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>8</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>9</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>10</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>11</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>12</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>13</span></div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row calendar-week">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>14</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>15</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>16</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>17</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>18</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>19</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>20</span></div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row calendar-week">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>21</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>22</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>23</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>24</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>25</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>26</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>27</span></div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row calendar-week">
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span></span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>28</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>29</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>30</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>1</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>2</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>3</span></div></div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 grid-cell"><div><div><span>4</span></div></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnkgroove/fvcxv9oo/

Comment: what's wrong with the current design, or could you please state the issue precisely?

Comment: i need to make it responsive thats why i'm using bootstrap